# Are there a function to assign some value to some certain elements of a matrix without using for loop?

Tags: matlab

I am new at matlab. I got a matrix and need to change its some elements. To find that elements I used find function. Find function returns the coordinates of elements which is suitable for the given condition right?

I used it like below and I need to change those elements which returns from the find function without using any for loop.

```
A = find(compressed_lena >= k*aoi & compressed_lena <=((k+1)*aoi)-1);
```

Do not care about variables (k, aoi). Compressed_lena is the matrix that I mentioned above. Am I doing anything wrong? If not, how can I assign some certain value to those elements that returns from find function and stored in A?

Comment: `compressed_lena(A) = new_value_or_vector_of_new_values`

Comment: That was an easy one :-D